# How to make bash alias work with command inclusion i.e. $() (the dollar sign and parenthesis)

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias

I used to have aliases like:

```
alias mount-open="sudo mount $(sudo blkid | gawk '/2tb-open/ { print substr($1, 0, 9) }') 2tb-open"
```

I can't be 100% sure that it was the same, but 100% it was a bash alias, not a bash function, and it had other command inclusion without the use of variables etc.

Now I can't make this work. If I put the double quotes (like in the example), it tries to run some sudo command on terminal startup. If I use single quotes and escape the quotes in the middle:

```
alias mount-open='sudo mount $(sudo blkid | gawk \'/2tb-open/ { print substr($1, 0, 9) }\') 2tb-open'
```

it says:

```
bash: .bashrc: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

---

*I suppose it has something to do with 'extra code' in the default Ubuntu bashrc compared to the Fedora one, which is rather lean. I mean, it worked on Ubuntu. A couple of years ago I installed Fedora and copied the bashrc file from my Ubuntu sytem to it, the aliases etc. worked. It worked in Fedora 32 (with the Ubuntu bashrc) a week ago. But now I had sort of a data loss and I'm trying to 'reinvent' this. Currently I'm using the default Fedora bashrc file, which had only like 15 lines initially*

Could anyone suggest how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: For the record [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)

Comment: You can escape single quotes inside an [ANSI-C quoted string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting): `echo $'Don\'t worry'`

Comment: You don't have these kind of quoting problems with functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes can't be escaped inside a single quoted string. You need to quit the double quotes and reenter them later:

```
alias mount-open='sudo mount $(sudo blkid | gawk '\''/2tb-open/ { print substr($1, 0, 9) }'\'') 2tb-open'
```

Comment: May I ask: did you mean 'single quotes cannot be escaped in a single quote string, while they can be escaped in the "unquoted bash command"? I.e. in `gawk '\''` the first quote closes the opening one (not shown). The second \' is an escaped quote passed directly to gawk, and the third one starts a single quoted string.

Comment: @user907860 Yes, this is what was meant.

Comment: It would arguably be easier to use a shell function in this case.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Definitely, but *not a bash function* was stated in the question.

Comment: Ah, I thought that was the user trying to recall what the had _before_, not what they wanted now. Seeing as functions are much more flexible than aliases, and in this case provides a safer quoting environment, a function may possible be a good alternative at least.

Answer (score 3):

It would be much easier with a function or a script:

```
mount-open() {
  sudo mount "$(
      sudo blkid |
        gawk '/2tb-open/ { print substr($1, 0, 9) }'
    )" 2tb-open
}
```

Though if you want to mount the device with label `2tb-open`,

```
mount-open() { sudo mount LABEL=2tb-open 2tb-open; }
```

should be enough.